# ng-repeat in 4 objects containing arrays and variables

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Below is my code where I'm using ng-repeat to load my data from the scope.My scope has 4 arrays 0,1,2,3.

```
<div class="card"  ng-repeat="x in configuration" >
    <div class="card-content">
        <p>Relay No
            <b>{{x[0].uid}}</b>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <p>Relay No
            <b>{{x[1].uid}}</b>
        </p>
    </div>......</div>
```

how to make my code single line using the $index to load all the four at a single call

```
<div class="card-content">
    <p>Relay No
        <b>{{x[$index+1].uid}}</b>
    </p>
</div>
```

configuration array

```
Array(4)
0:{configuration: Array(3), _id: "5a795661ca76d51804848731", uid:25,gid: 2}
1:{configuration: Array(4), _id: "5a795667ca76d51804848732", uid: 26, gid:2}
2:{configuration: Array(0), _id: "5a79566dca76d51804848733", uid: 27, gid: 2}
3:{configuration: Array(0), _id: "5a795674ca76d51804848734", uid: 28, gid: 2}
```

below is the complete object. I'm getting this from the backend.The object contains config,uid and gid.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a795661ca76d51804848731"),
    "configuration" : [
        {
            "cid" : "HgvE319bbibJ",
            "_on" : "15:01",
            "_off" : "15:02"
        }
        ],
    "uid" : 25,
    "gid" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a795667ca76d51804848732"),
    "configuration" : [
        {
            "cid" : "tJ1rMNYfrjl4",
            "_on" : "15:03",
            "_off" : "15:04"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "C9aOF1jZ51H9",
            "_on" : "15:07",
            "_off" : "15:08"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "ge5ZZxcZzeGO",
            "_on" : "15:09",
            "_off" : "15:10"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "e8S0atEJ1Ans",
            "_on" : "12:57",
            "_off" : "12:58"
        }
    ],
    "uid" : 26,
    "gid" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a79566dca76d51804848733"),
    "configuration" : [ ],
    "uid" : 27,
    "gid" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a795674ca76d51804848734"),
    "configuration" : [ ],
    "uid" : 28,
    "gid" : 2
}
```

Comment: can you also show what `configuration` array looks like?

Comment: You have 4 arrays, or you have one array with 4 items? This is not clear, so please show us the `configuration` in your controller as requested by Aleksey

Comment: I suppose you have one array of objects. `[ { }, { } ...{ } ]` or a collection

Comment: @AlekseySolovey please check the array format. I have updated it

Comment: Can you show the contents of the configuration object too ?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey please check it now

Comment: @rach8garg please check it now. I have updated my code

Comment: @ManojSai your `configuration` array has `configuration` arrays inside of it? Either way, it's hard to visualise what is the right property to use, don't you just need `<b>{{x.uid}}</b>`?

Comment: Are you iterating over this -> configuration: Array(3) or the outer Array ?

Comment: @rach8garg check it. I have posted

Comment: @AlekseySolovey That doesn't works bro. If i use <b>{{x[0].uid}}</b> i can load uid:26, <b>{{x[1].uid}}</b> then i can load uid:27. I just want to load everything in one call

Comment: @ManojSai then `<b>{{x[$index].uid}}</b>` has to work. Any reason why not?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey <b>{{x[$index].uid}}</b> even tried this.This is loading only the first value.i,e uid:25. Remaining values are not displaying. I need 25-28 in one call :)

Comment: check my answer below. @ManojSai

Answer (score 0):

The problem is change your _id as integer. Its should not be in that format

```
<div class="card"  ng-repeat="x in list" >
<div class="card-content">
<p>Relay No
<b>{{x.uid}}</b>
</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does he need to use $index if he is inside the object itself ? @BlueCloud

Comment: your object is array or not

Comment: save all your idividual object in list and try it

Comment: its working fine i was save your all objects in list and its working fine

Comment: I have posted the structure in the code please check it out. inside one object there is one array called config, one uid and one gid. In total there are four

Comment: Can you please send me the link to your plunker :)

Comment: Yes, Thats fine, You have four Objects. Add those objects in an array like $scope.list = [ ]; then push those four objects in this array, iterate it (x in list track) and get UID as x.UID . This should work

Comment: $scope.configuration = [],
            $http.get('/api/list')
            .then(function (result) {
                $scope.configuration = result.data;
 didn't work out .

Comment: check my plunker above. its working. The proble is with the _id in the object. it should be a data type not like  ObjectId("5a795667ca76d51804848732"),

Answer (score 0):

This should simply work.

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="(key, item) in configuration">
    <div class="card-content">
        <p>Relay No
            <b>{{item.uid}}</b>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here the configuration is equal to the main object you pasted above. Its a collection basically.

Check here for simple explanation:

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-repeat.asp

Comment: didn't work :( not loading any value from the object

Answer (score 0):

@rach8garg - UID and Configuration are Variables of a same object. So you cant get UID from configuration

Comment: Check the explanation below snippet: I am supposing outer object i.e scope variable is also named configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `ObjectId` from the collection otherwise there will be a reference error.

Here is the working example.

```js
    var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
     
     app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.configuration = [{
    "configuration" : [
        {
            "cid" : "HgvE319bbibJ",
            "_on" : "15:01",
            "_off" : "15:02"
        }
        ],
    "uid" : 25,
    "gid" : 2
     },
     {
    "configuration" : [
        {
            "cid" : "tJ1rMNYfrjl4",
            "_on" : "15:03",
            "_off" : "15:04"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "C9aOF1jZ51H9",
            "_on" : "15:07",
            "_off" : "15:08"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "ge5ZZxcZzeGO",
            "_on" : "15:09",
            "_off" : "15:10"
        },
        {
            "cid" : "e8S0atEJ1Ans",
            "_on" : "12:57",
            "_off" : "12:58"
        }
       ],
          "uid" : 26,
            "gid" : 2
            },
           {
         "configuration" : [ ],
         "uid" : 27,
         "gid" : 2
           },
       {
    "configuration" : [ ],
    "uid" : 28,
    "gid" : 2
      }];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<h1 ng-repeat="x in configuration">{{x.uid}}</h1>

<script>

</script>

</body>
```

Comment: that's the problem, but those ids are primary keys generated by mogoDb. :( any other way to sort it out ?

Comment: They may be generated by mongoDb. If the are received over the network in a JSON then it should fail at that point itself. Its not a valid JSON at all.

Comment: Thanks :) I will raise a complaint to my backend team to look into it. Tq very much

Comment: upvoted.I'm new vibe to StackOverflow so it can't be viewed till i get reputations. I only get downvotes for my question formation :P